# Enabling SSL Support for nginx while installed through phusion passenger gem

Tags: nginx, ssl-certificate, passenger

Does installing passenger and nginx using rubygems by doing

gem install passenger

Install the passenger with ssl support ? . If not how can I re-install using rubygems but with ssl support ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems it does. All i needed to do was add the configuration for enabling ssl on the conf files